# How to add namespace prefix to class element in c#

Tags: c#, xml

```
 [XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true, Namespace = "http://www.example.org/schema/SCRIPT")]
    public  class Identification
    {
        public string DEANumber { get; set; }
        public uint NPI { get; set; }
    }
```

```html
<someprefix:Identification>
          <someprefix:DEANumber>FF1234567</DEANumber>
          <someprefix:NPI>1619967999</NPI>
  </someprefix:Identification>
```

How to assign namespace  prefix to class elements

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a `XmlSerializerNamespaces` as such :

```
var id = new Identification()
{
    DEANumber = "qwe",
    NPI = 123,
};

var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Identification));
var xmlns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
xmlns.Add("someprefix", "http://www.example.org/schema/SCRIPT");

serializer.Serialize(Console.Out, id, xmlns);
```

Comment: i want to add  multiple prefix in complete XML so is there anyway add at class level

Comment: You'll have to specify them at the root level (in the `XmlSerializer.Serailize` method).